# Hibernate and Java persistence API - java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NONE

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jetty

I am seeing this exception in my Jetty 9 logs. I have the gradle dependencies set below. Do you all have any idea why I am getting the java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NONE exception.

Gradle dependencies -

```
compile 'redis.clients:jedis:2.6.2',
        "javax.persistence:persistence-api:${javaPersistenceVersion}",
        "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:${hibernateVersion}",
        "org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:${hibernateVersion}",
        "mysql:mysql-connector-java:${mysqlVersion}"
```

Properties -

```
hibernateVersion=4.3.8.Final
mysqlVersion=5.1.34
slf4jVersion=1.7.5
javaServletVersion=2.5
javaPersistenceVersion=1.0.2
```

Exception -

```
SEVERE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to
 the HTTP container
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NONE
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.<init>(AbstractQueryImpl.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.<init>(QueryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.<init>(QueryImpl.java:87)
```

.....

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NONE
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:420)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
```

.....

```
Caused by: 
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NONE
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.<init>(AbstractQueryImpl.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.<init>(QueryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.<init>(QueryImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:328)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this does the trick, but Hibernate 4.3 is a JPA 2.1 implementation, so...

> javaPersistenceVersion=1.0.2

...seems way off?

JPA version is show in the [Hibernate ORM 4.3 documentation](http://hibernate.org/orm/documentation/4.3/)

br,
Jens